# What test is appropriate test for confidence interval for proportion sample (R test)

Tags: t-test, proportion, wilcoxon-signed-rank

Seeking appropriate R test approach for small sample. Given 160 units randomly sampled, 140 met the requirements approved living quarters by county standards. If we desire a 90% confidence interval for the proportion of home units that meet the approved living quarters by county standard in this year.

We have 160 home units 
We have 140 home units meeting standards
We have  20 home units no meeting standards

What is an appropriate R test for this sample of proportion of home units that meet the approved living quarters by county standard in this year? Looking for R test approach.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can have a look at `binom.test`. It provides Clopper-Pearson confidence intervals for a proportion.

Comment: Does binom.test work with small samples? I just need to test with 160 and 140 and difference for 20 homes for confidence interval. Let me check binom.test

Comment: Yes, it is exact in the sense that it is never too optimistic.

Comment: Exact binomial test

data:  c(160, 140)
number of successes = 160, number of trials = 300, p-value = 0.2726
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4751235 0.5908784
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.5333333

Answer (score 0):

binom.test(c(160, 140), conf.level = 0.90)

data:  c(160, 140)
number of successes = 160, number of trials = 300, p-value = 0.2726
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
90 percent confidence interval:
 0.4842001 0.5819727
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.5333333